# VisualEditor not connecting to Parsoid server in MediaWiki 1.35

Tags: docker, mediawiki, visual-editor, mediawiki-installation, parsoid

I'm trying to set up a MediaWiki wiki in Docker. I am using the official MedaiWiki image [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/mediawiki), version 1.35.1 . Once I get the wiki up and running, I run into [this issue when attempting to run the VisualEditor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JU0r.png).

I'm a little confused about why the Parsoid server is necessary to use the VisualEditor. It was my understanding that this was unnecessary as of version 1.35.1. Is this incorrect? Or am I configuring the MediaWiki wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like VisualEditor won't work with short URLs:
https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T270376